# How do I use umlauts (ä, ü, ö) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code

```
print('ö')
```

gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elect\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\elect\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\elect\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 288, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Users\elect\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 257, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "C:\Users\elect\source\repos\TFT\TFT\TFT.py", line 1
    print('�')
             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 0: invalid start byte
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have tried various variations of the encoding and decoding methods that I have seen on other questions regarding special characters in python, but none of them worked.

Comment: What encoding did you choose for the file in your editor?

Comment: And how are you running your code exactly on what platform with which version (python, gcc and platform)?

Comment: Python 3.10.7 using Visual Studio on Windows 11 Home

Comment: It looks to me like Visual Studio saved the file as ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you, I have change the Visual Studio settings as well as the locale for non-Unicode programs under Windows and it's working now